# How i can access (display) the picture stored on path outside the server?

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am developping an application where the user can create an account and his profil (name, phone number and a **picture**). 
The problem is about the picture, when user upload the picture i store it on server disk directory (outside app context) and i save the path of picture in database. 
I my app i want to display the picture i save on user profil page.

How i can access (display) the picture stored on path outside the server ?

I use Tomcat 7, Spring MVC 3.

Comment: One way is to use file I/O and read the file stream and use that stream to display

Comment: I want to display picture in my page using <img src="imagepath/picture.jpg"/>. I am afraid about using file I/O because it can slow my web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would not be able to show it using putting local server path in image source. The html image tag reads the path when rendered in a web browser and your web browser will not have access to local path on your server. You will either have to create you app URL, which returns you the stream of your image or place that image in some web server and create URL of that image accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If by outside server, you mean outside the server directory in a different drive, then try the absolute path of the pictures first. And then when you are confident your pictures can be displayed in your page, then try trimming the path and refreshing the page so you get the relative path needed.

Comment: my question was not clear i think. I mean i store my picture on a server directory but outside the web app.

Comment: The answer still applies. I use absolute paths myself. My paths look like /var/vault/fs/name_of_picture.jpg and the webapp is located in /usr/local/tomcat7/webapps/

Comment: @happyCoder_: I don't think that is correct. Where do you mention your image path and how does the browser display the image? You can use path of an image like this but it has to come from some context and that context could be of your web application or from web server directly. Otherwise it won't work. image source path are used while rendering the html in browser and your browser must be able to access the image source path somehow.